# WhenEvent for equation defined outside NDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, event-detection

Say i want to use WhenEvent to specify a value of R[s] when my function Dsonic[s]==-3.
For some reason i get an error message. Seems that mathematica cannot read my function.
Here is my code.
Thank you

```
q0 = 5.3;
ε0 = 2.2;
Γ = 5/3;
μ = 0.001;
ψ0 = 40;
l = μ/2;
Ω0 = 10.112;

h0[s_] := Sqrt[1 - (R[s]* μ)/(l^2 + R[s]^2)] 
U0[s_] := (4 π ψ0 (ε0^2 - h0[s]^2 (q0 Δ0[s]^(1 - Γ) + 1)^2))^(1/2)
sM0[s_] := Δ0[s] + q0 Δ0[s]^(2 - Γ)
sG[s_] := sM0[s]/U0[s]
Dsonic[s_] := (-(-1 + Γ) ε0^2 + (-2 + Γ) ε0^2 (q0 Δ0[s]^(1 - Γ) + 1) +
h0[s]^2 (q0 Δ0[s]^(1 - Γ) + 1)^3)  
dΔ0[s_] := (q0 Δ0[s] + 
Δ0[s]^Γ) ε0^2 (-2 R[s]^2 + (l^2 + R[s]^2) F[s]) Δ0[s]^(2 Γ)

dF[s_] := F[s]*Dsonic[s] + (F[s]^2 (h0[s]^2 - sM0[s]))/(
4 π R[s]^2 sG[s]^2)*Dsonic[s]



Rinit = 0.05;
ξinit = 1.8;
Δinit = ((ξinit - 1)/q0)^(1/(1 - Γ));
Finit = 1.2;
smax = 0.0002233658;
sol = NDSolve[{F'[s] == dF[s], Δ0'[s] == dΔ0[s]*Dsonic[s], 
R'[s] == Dsonic[s],  F[0] == Finit, Δ0[0] == Δinit, R[0] == Rinit,
WhenEvent[Dsonic[s] == -3, Print[R[s]]]}, {F, Δ0, R}, {s, 0, 
smax}];

ParametricPlot[{R[s], Dsonic[s]} /. sol, {s, 0, smax}, 
AspectRatio -> Full]
```

Answer (score 5):

Use `Evaluate`:

```
WhenEvent[Evaluate[Dsonic[s] == -3], Print[R[s]]]
```

`WhenEvent` is a bit tricky in that the event is constructed from the code. Any state variables must be literally present in the code.  If they appear in a function, use `Evaluate` or inject the code with something like `With[]`.  Another alternative is to make the state variables arguments of the function `Dsonic`.

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Appendix*

Alternative 1:

```
With[{evt = Dsonic[s] == -3},
 sol = NDSolve[{F'[s] == dF[s], \[CapitalDelta]0'[s] == 
     d\[CapitalDelta]0[s]*Dsonic[s], R'[s] == Dsonic[s], 
    F[0] == Finit, \[CapitalDelta]0[0] == \[CapitalDelta]init, 
    R[0] == Rinit, WhenEvent[evt, Print[R[s]]]}, {F, \[CapitalDelta]0,
     R}, {s, 0, smax}]
 ]
```

Alternative 2:

```
(* rather a lot of code refactoring to add arguments to
 *    h0[], U0[], sM0[], sG[], Dsonic[], d\[CapitalDelta]0[], dF[]
 * for the state variables F[s], \[CapitalDelta]0[s], R[s]
 *)
(* coding left as an exercise for the reader *)
```

Comment: I am not quite sure i understand the alternative. But this works so thank you very much

Comment: @Agaph You're welcome. Added the `With[]` alternative to the answer, assuming you meant that alternative.

Comment: Thank you again.
I have been doing the last tedious method which really counter productive and I try to avoid it but didn't know how till you answered. The expressions are quite large.
This is just a working example so i can answer my question